# Haskell and postgresql - build error "The program pg_config is required but it could not be found."

Tags: postgresql, haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-persistent

I am currently learning haskell and just tried using postgresql as a database.

I generated my project with stack (`stack new <name>` -> `stack setup` -> `stack build`)
and then all I changed was adding the dependencies needed to persistent and postgresql to the
package.yaml file (under "dependencies:").

These are:

- persistent
- persistent-postgresql
- persistent-template

This however results in a failing build with the following message:

postgresql-libpq     > setup.exe: The program 'pg_config' is required but it could not be found.

postgresql-libpq     >

--  While building package postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.2 using:
      C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\stack14388\postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.2.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\e626a42b configure --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\pkgdb --libdir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\lib --bindir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\bin --datadir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\share --libexecdir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\etc --docdir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\doc\postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.2 --htmldir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\doc\postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.2 --haddockdir=C:\sr\snapshots\365a3dde\doc\postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.2 --dependency=Cabal=Cabal-2.4.1.0-5rQrtDcYhR2LOcYye7obEr --dependency=Win32=Win32-2.6.1.0 --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 -f-use-pkg-config --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\lib --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\bin --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue and why it even occurs?

Do I have to install postgresql just for being able to run build the project? If so, how would you
do this in production, when the database could basically lie everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Haskell is trying to build with the PostgreSQL client shared library `libpq.dll` and uses `pg_config` at build time to determine where PostgreSQL is installed and how it was built.

That would mean that you have to install PostgreSQL on the machine where you build Haskell, including the header files, build environment or however it is called by the installer.

For running Haskell you would only need `libpq.dll` and the dependent shared libraries.

Comment: I tried a few new things, none of which really helped. I installed postgresql and followed several stackoverflow or gitlab issue suggestions on how to add the libpq.dll to my build file. However, no matter what I try, the error remains the same. How can I ensure the both libpq.dll and pg_config is loaded?

Comment: They don't have to be loaded, they have to be installed. All you have to do is set the `PATH` environment variable to include the directory that contains `pg_config`. If you have trouble, ask somebody for help who knows Windows.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that was all, this and adding the path to the build file solved the problem, thanks. Now however, while building correctly, it complains about libssl-1_1-x64.dll being missing, but it is present in the /bin folder

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that all the directories with required DLLs are on the `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue in Ubuntu with the following command:

```sh
apt install libpq-dev
```